# Subsonic error: The ORDER BY clause is invalid...., unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified

Tags: group-by, aggregate, subsonic

I'm using Subsonic 2.1 and I'm having an error with the next query:

```
SqlQuery queryResTitle = new Select(
    new Aggregate(ResTitle.ResourceTitleIDColumn, "ResourceTitleID", AggregateFunction.GroupBy),
    new Aggregate(ResTitle.ResourceTitleColumn, "ResourceTitle", AggregateFunction.GroupBy),
    new Aggregate(VenVendor.TitleColumn, "Title", AggregateFunction.GroupBy),
    new Aggregate(ResTitleStatus.StatusColumn, "Status", AggregateFunction.GroupBy))
  .From(Tables.ResTitleOngoing)
  .InnerJoin(ResTitleStatus.ResourceTitleIDColumn, ResTitle.ResourceTitleIDColumn)
  .LeftOuterJoin(VenVendor.VendorIDColumn, ResTitle.VendorIDColumn);
```

I'm getting the error:

> "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in
>   views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table
>   expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is
>   also specified"

I also added `.Top("1")` but I still got the same error.

Comment: How is `ResTitleOngoing` linked with the other tables? Looks like there's a join missing.  Though I still don't see where the `ORDER BY` is coming from - can you post the generated SQL?

Comment: What database are you using? (add it to the tags)

Answer (score 1):

You should debug the generated query that SubSonic returns:

```
var queryString = queryResTitle.BuildSqlStatement();
```

and execute it in your favorite database administration tool.
Maybe you can figure out what's going wrong.